# How enforce Android to re-read GPS position?

Tags: java, android, gps

I try to write application, which shows GPS coordinates on button click.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    EditText editText;
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    LocationManager locationManager;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation("gps");
    editText.setText(location.toString());
}
```

Is problem: while in first time I got coordinates of location with time of GPS reading, second click get the same location. Even when I stop program and run again, it get the same location!
How enforce to refresh reading GPS?

Comment: Have you tried putting the location manager into a function of it's and having it return the coordinates each time it is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

> while in first time I got coordinates of location with time of GPS reading, second click get the same location

That is not surprising.

> Even when I stop program and run again, it get the same location!

That too is not surprising.

> How enforce to refresh reading GPS?

Generally speaking, you don't. There is no requirement that the device has to have a fresh update just because you request the last-known location. It may be physically impossible to provide a new location fix. And, if you are not calling `requestLocationUpdates()`, it is very possible for `getLastKnownLocation()` to simply return `null`.

Your parameters to `requestLocationUpdates()` may have some impact for how aggressively the device tries to update GPS, versus saving power. However, there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get best provider that available to fetch the Location data , 
using this code before you get the location

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
```

and in your `getLastKnownLocation`  pass the best Location Provider to get the location like this

```
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider );
```